# jQuery wrapping of classes

Tags: jquery

Hi I've got this list of li's, containing dynamic classes(not always the same). There's always a `.connected` class and two sets of "numberclasses".

```
<ul>
  <li class="connected 34 22"></li>
  <li class="connected 54 11"></li>
  <li class="connected 11 54"></li>
  <li class="connected 22 34"></li>
  <li class="connected 12 31"></li>
  <li class="connected 31 12"></li>  
</ul>
```

I want to wrap/sort the classes in groups like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <!-- Group consisting elements with classes 12 or 31 -->
      <li class="connected 12 31">foo</li>
      <li class="connected 31 12">foo</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <!-- Group consisting elements with classes 22 or 34 -->
      <li class="connected 34 22">foo</li>
      <li class="connected 22 34">foo</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

How can i do this?

-- Update --

**My sorting logic is that I want to wrap elements that contains the same classes.**

I've tried something like `$('.22').wrapAll('<ul/>');` but since the classes are generated and not static i can't find a way to do it.

-- Update 2 --

Think i know how I can do this. But I'm gonna need a little help.

First i push all class values from the list items to an array.
Then remove all duplicates in that array.
Later on iterate the array and wrap these array values in ul's. `$('array[1]').wrapAll('<ul/>');`

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cZYe4/)

Comment: What exactly is your sorting logic? It's not clear from your example.

Comment: In addition to the point above, Stack Overflow is not a free coding service, although people frequently do respond with code. What have you tried? What approach would you take? What other approaches have you considered and rejected? What does your own code to do it look like? Why aren't you happy with it? You get the idea. People are happy to *help*, but when it's "please write this for me," it's off-topic.

Comment: What if elements could be in multiple groups?

Comment: To work around the problem of having generated class, you can read the classes of the list items at runtime. e.g. `$('li:first').attr('class')` will return `connected 34 22`. You can then parse these values to get the classes you will have at runtime.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean @user122211 but thank you for trying to help! I've updated the question with a jsfiddle link with my problem. Is this somewhere near what u ment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JX58j/***

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var classMap = [];

    $('.connected').each(function(idx) {
        var $this = $(this);

        // get the classes of each LI and sort them (It's easier to compare this way)
        var sortedClasses = $this.attr('class').split(' ').sort().toString().replace(/,/g, '-');

        // store the resulting sorted classes as data
        $this.data('grouping', sortedClasses);


        // add the 'grouping' to the classMap array if it isn't already in there
        if ($.inArray(sortedClasses, classMap) == -1) {
            classMap.push(sortedClasses);
        }
    });

    // create the ULs determined by the length of classMap
    for (i = 0; i < classMap.length; i++) {
        $('<ul>')
            .appendTo('#old-ul')
            .addClass(classMap[i]);           
    }

    // move the LIs from old UL to the new ULs
    $('.connected').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $grouping = $this.data('grouping');
        $this.appendTo('ul.' + $grouping);
    });

    // wrap the ULs inside #old-ul in an LI tag so it validates
    $('#old-ul ul').wrap('<li />');


});
```